# How to allow to run su instantly after I added the user to the appropriate group

Tags: permissions, su

I have the `su` executable with the following permissions:

```
bash-4.2# ls -la /bin/su
-rws--s--- 1 root wheel 59930 Sep 14  2012 ./su
```

When I am logged in as a user, not in the `wheel` group and try to run `su`, I get an error, which is correct:

```
bash-4.2$ su
bash: /bin/su: Permission denied
```

After that I add this user to `wheel` group from `root`:

```
bash-4.2# usermod -a -G wheel user
```

But for the same terminal session I still can't run `su`:

```
bash-4.2$ su
bash: /bin/su: Permission denied
```

For the new sessions I can run `su`.
How to allow to run `su` instantly after I added the user to the appropriate group?

Comment: Joseph's `newgrp` answer is correct - but it applies ONLY to the shell that you run it in, so if you have multiple shells running it's easy to forget which you've run `newgrp` in and which you haven't.  It can be simpler/easier to just logout and login again.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simply have the user run

```
newgrp wheel
```

This will start a new shell with the group ID changed to that of `wheel`. If you want to start a new shell and kill off the previous one, use

```
exec newgrp wheel
```

instead.

This is because the kernel still has the previous groupset associated with the currently running processes.

Comment: How can I run in in graphical terminal emulator? When I run `newgrp wheel` as a user, it asks for some password. Even when I type root password, it says: Invalid password

Comment: @user4035 Are we by any chance talking about a networked environment with an authentication mechanism like NIS/LDAP? If that's the case, it may be that the new group associations were not properly propagated to the client machine(s) yet.

Comment: No, it's my local machine. I login as user, then run X Session, then start a terminal and run `su` there to switch to root. I tried to run "newgrp wheel", but it asks for some password: `bash-4.2$ newgrp wheel
Password: ` root password doesn't work

Comment: @user4035 According to the [man-page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?newgrp+1) this will be the password of the user - not the password for root. This is logical, since this is basically the same as a new login.

Comment: @Nils but a new authentication wouldn't be required if the user account was properly added to the group. At least that's how it is on my Debian box(es).

Comment: Do you authenticate with NIS/LDAP or something alike? Then there might be a caching mechanism that prevents debian from asking again. Does `last` show a new login after `newgrp`?

Comment: @Nils That was my instinct too :). The OP rejected this, however. See the second and the third comments.

Comment: I am asking about YOUR setup. Having NIS/LDAP with you but not with the OP would explain it.

Comment: @Nils Sorry, my bad. Yes, I'm using NIS indeed.

Comment: Yes debian has some nice SSO features. It can even allow you a login with the ssh-passphrase. In the background it will start the `ssh-agent` to store that phrase. If you do not know about this it seems like magic that you can use ssh without phrase just after login...

Comment: @Nils I just tried on a Debian box where I authenticate without NIS and it didn't require any password after `newgrp`.

Comment: @Nils This user doesn't have a password. Seems, that it was asking me the password of wheel group, that I don't know. When I set the user password, it started to work. I am using Slackware 14.0

Comment: @user4035 That is the expected behavior according to the man-page.

Comment: Note that this answer is inaccurate since the effect of `newgrp wheel` is not to let "add the user to the wheel group" to take effect, the effect is that __the primary GID of the user changed__ which is fundamentally different - e.g. newly created files will have the new GID.