# Added user supplementary group, but 'groups(1)' not showing change

Tags: users, group

I'm trying to add myself to the *fuse* user group but it doesn't look like the change is taking effect even though */etc/group* looks correct after invoking *addgroup* or *usermod*.

I've tried both ...

```
sudo addgroup fjohnson fuse
```

and

```
sudo usermod -a -G fuse fjohnson
```

*/etc/group* shows the change

```
fuse:x:104:fjohnson
```

but I can't read

```
-rw-r----- 1 root fuse 215 Oct 16 10:39 /etc/fuse.conf
```

as

```
cat: /etc/fuse.conf: Permission denied
```

and *groups(1)* returns

```
fjohnson adm dialout cdrom plugdev lpadmin admin sambashare
```

Comment: Have you logged out and logged back in after the change?

Comment: See [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91271/how-to-allow-to-run-su-instantly-after-i-added-the-user-to-the-appropriate-group/91274#91274) as well.

Comment: @esnyder- I've got too many things open to do that. Any idea why that would work? (It sounds like it would from what I have been reading)

Comment: @esnyder,@Joseph R. - I've upvoted both of you since your comments were both correct.

Comment: Something related that tripped me up briefly was using ssh ControlMaster to log into all my boxes.
Logging out and back in is insufficient to refresh groups as the session is effectively kept open.
In this case you need to log out, "ssh -O exit <host>" and log back in.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

When you add a group to a user, this user should logout/login in order for the change to take effect.

You can also use `newgrp` command.

```
  $ id
  uid=1000(romain) gid=1000(romain) groups=1000(romain),24(cdrom),25(floppy),27(sudo),29(audio),30(dip),44(video),46(plugdev),105(scanner),110(bluetooth),112(netdev)
  $ sudo addgroup romain fuse
  Adding user `romain' to group `fuse' ...
  Adding user romain to group fuse
  Done.
  $ id
  uid=1000(romain) gid=1000(romain) groups=1000(romain),24(cdrom),25(floppy),27(sudo),29(audio),30(dip),44(video),46(plugdev),105(scanner),110(bluetooth),112(netdev)
  $ newgrp fuse
  $ id
  uid=1000(romain) gid=103(fuse) groups=1000(romain),24(cdrom),25(floppy),27(sudo),29(audio),30(dip),44(video),46(plugdev),103(fuse),105(scanner),110(bluetooth),112(netdev)
```

Comment: Note that the effect of `newgrp fuse` is not to let "Adding user romain to group fuse" to take effect, the effect is that __the primary GID of the user changed__ which is fundamentally different - e.g. newly created files will have gid=103 rather than gid=1000.

Comment: This is answer is not what i was looking for.  im having same issue, when i add user to a group, it shows in `/etc/group` but doesnt show in `groups`, i have exited, logged back in, still not showing.  I do have ssh multiplex on, i wonder if thats it, however I feel as if exiting should be enough.  This is for Centos6, and this problem is consistent across multiple servers.  newgrp just seems to be a temp workaround, where i want to set user perms, and want to make sure its working right.

Comment: @JakubKlinkovský - call `newgrp fuse` then `newgrp romain`, as discussed in detail in this answer - https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/613608/247579

Comment: @BrianThomas - 'newgrp' opens a new shell, and in that shell the new group shows in `groups`.  It is true that if you leave that shell, the effect is reversed without side effects.  If that is not enough and you are looking for alternative to reboot (because logout doesn't work) then try looking at the second part of my answer https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/613608/247579 , where I discuss killing a user process titled `(sd-pam)` which uniquely didn't get killed by the logout.  May be related to `systemd`.  Worked for me in ubuntu 20.04.