# Accessing other folder

Tags: permissions, filesystems

I'm having difficulty with groups and permissions.

- I have user `A` part of group `A` that manages a folder `F`.
- A second user `B` part of group `B` must access folder `F` and its content.
- I added user `B` to group `A` but every time `B` tries to access folder `F` gets the message saying:

  ```
  'Permission Denied'.
  ```

Is this the correct way to achieve that or do I need to do something more?

I'm using CentOS 6.4.

Comment: Does A group have the execute bit set on this folder ? Can you show us the folder's permissions ?

Comment: Also look at [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91271/how-to-allow-to-run-su-instantly-after-i-added-the-user-to-the-appropriate-group) in case you haven't logged out since you applied these changes.

Comment: @Vinz. No If I give ls -ld F I get "drwx------."

Comment: There're no group permissions. Do `chmod 750 F` and it should be OK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are the permissions, ownership, and groups for folder `F`? These need to be set such that group `A` is set as the group on the folder, and the permissions need to allow members of group `A` access to the folder.

#### Example

```
$ ls -ld F
drwxrwxr-x 2 saml blah 4096 Nov 28 08:38 F
```

In the above example, directory `F`, notice that the group `blah` is set, and that the permissions are `rwx` for the group. This would allow any members of that group access to this directory.

#### Fixes

If the above isn't the case then you can adjust the permissions like so:

```
$ chmod g+rwx F
```

To change ownership:

```
$ chgrp blah F
```

Comment: @sim. No If I give ls -ld F I get "drwx------. A A". I think that the ownership os to user A.

Comment: @AbruzzoForteeGentile Then you need to alter group permissions for `F`: `chmod -R g+rX F`

Comment: @AbruzzoForteeGentile - Glad this resolved your issue. Please be sure to mark this answer as accepted so that others know your issue's been resolved.

Comment: Done as it should be!