# What is the difference between gid and groups

Tags: permissions, files

I was wondering about the following behavior:

I have three users `A`, `B` and `C`. `A` creates a folder and changes the group ownership to `C`'s group.

```
mkdir fold
chgrp C fold
chmod g+rw fold
```

Now I add `B` to the `C` user group by

```
usermod -a -G C B
```

and `id B` gives me `uid=1002(B) gid=1002(B) groups=1002(B),1003(C)`. Trying to change the content of `fold` (`mkdir fold/fold2` or `touch fold/test`) as user `B`, however, gives me a permission denied and only `A` and  `C` can change the contents of that folder. What is the reason? If I change the `gid` of `B` to `C` by  `usermod -g C B`, but this can't be the proper way right?

Comment: Take a look at this: [How to allow to run su instantly after I added the user to the appropriate group](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91271/how-to-allow-to-run-su-instantly-after-i-added-the-user-to-the-appropriate-group/91274)

Comment: @JosephR. mmh I actually rebooted the machine. Anyways I'll try your suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

Accessing a directory requires the execute (`x`) permission. The read (`r`) permission only lets you list the directory's contents, not access that content. The write (`w`) permission is useless without `x`.

```
chmod g+x fold
```

---

*(For the benefit of future visitors with similar, but not identical symptoms)*

In the output of `id`, `gid` is the user's [primary group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_identifier#Primary_vs._supplementary) and `groups` lists all the supplementary groups as well. The primary group is the one listed in the `passwd` file and the supplementary groups are the ones listed in the `group` file.

The membership of a user in a group is only meaningful to the login system. After login, there is no relationship between users and groups. Each process, starting with the login process, has a primary user¹, a primary group, and any number of supplementary groups. Thus a change of the user and group databases only takes effect in sessions started after the change. In a nutshell: after adding a user to a group, log out and back in.

¹ <sub>Two, actually: effective and real — but I won't go into that here as it only applied to setuid/setgid programs.</sub>

Comment: No, `w` on a directory means permission to change the directory, i.e., add/delete/rename file names in it. You'd need `x` to access the contents (files) in the directory, which is quite different.

Comment: Today, a process can belong to many groups simultaneously. And that "today" is older than Linux, IIRC.

Comment: @vonbrand Yes, all these groups are supplementary groups. The principal group is relevant for a few things, such as which group a newly-created file belongs to under SysV semantics.