# Not able to switch to root user via command line

Tags: centos, permissions, su

On my centos 7 vps server, to secure my server I disabled root login via ssh. I created a new user called erdem and login with that user via ssh. After I login via ssh with user erdem, I would like to switch to root user with su command or su -s command. When I do that I get this error:

```
-bash: /usr/bin/su: Permission denied
```

How can I give permission to user called erdem so I can switch with su or su -s command to root.

The output of `ls -l /usr/bin/su`:

```
 -rwsr-x--- 1 root wheel /usr/bin/su
```

I tried to add the user into wheel group but it still gives the same error.

I used bellow command

```
gpasswd -a erdem wheel
```

Solved: I needed to logout and login again.

Comment: Error apart, what you want to obtain is more commonly done via `sudo -s`. Doesn’t it work for you ?

Comment: `su` is also a valid means to become root, particularly if `sudo` is not yet installed, or the newly-created non-root user is not yet in `sudoers`.  OP, can you please add the output of the following to your question:  `ls -l /usr/bin/su`

Comment: when I do that it asks for a password for the user and when I type it I get this message erdem is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.

Comment: `su` expects the target user's password (root in this case). `sudo` expects the password of the user executing the command (yours).  `su` on some systems can only be executed by users in particular groups (`wheel` on BSD, for example), but I'm unsure how this works on CentOS.

Comment: @DopeGhoti it returns -rwsr-x--- 1 root wheel /usr/bin/su

Comment: @Kusalananda I don't want the user has root privileges. I want to be able to switch to root. thanks.

Comment: @ErdemEce This is what I assumed as well. My comment refers to you wanting to switch to root using either `su` or `sudo` and addresses the possibility that you used the wrong password.  `su` asks for the root password, `sudo` asks for your password.

Comment: @Kusalananda when I type su it doesn't ask for password it straight returns -bash: /usr/bin/su: Permission denied error

Comment: The user you created is not member of the `wheel` group and thus is not allowed to run `su`. It is also apparently not in any group allowed by your `sudo` configuration either. How did you create that user ?

Comment: Please add details by editing the question, not by adding them to the comments.

Comment: @DopeGhoti i edited my question.

Comment: Thank you.  After adding your user to the `wheel` group, you will need that user to log out and log back in again to refresh its group memberships.

Comment: @DopeGhoti that did it. It's a simple step but I couldn't figure it out. Thanks a lot.

Comment: duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/91271/4778

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The permissions for `su` look abnormal to me.  Here are the permissions I see on another `CentOS` machine:

```
-rwsr-xr-x. 1 root root 32208 Mar 14 10:37 /usr/bin/su
```

Note that your copy of `su` does *not* have the execute permission for users not in the `wheel` group, who are not already the root user.

On your system, no one will be able to `su` even knowing the root password if they are not in the `wheel` group.

Comment: after adding the user wheel group I didn't know I needed to logout and login again. Thanks.

Comment: This is the traditional way. The purpose of group `wheel` is to be able to use `su` to change to root. I think the check was originally in the command, as doing it this way prevents users switching to another non-root user (with password).